# Error logging in to a Microsoft account I'm already logged in to

Tags: microsoft-account

I have a problem that is confusing me.

I am already logged in to my Microsoft account and want to find my BitLocker recovery key.

According to this Microsoft support article, *[Finding your BitLocker recovery key in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/finding-your-bitlocker-recovery-key-in-windows-6b71ad27-0b89-ea08-f143-056f5ab347d6)*, the key can be retrieved from my Microsoft account at the following URL: [myaccount.microsoft.com/device-list](https://myaccount.microsoft.com/device-list)

If I try to navigate to that URL, even though I am already logged in, I am redirected to a Microsoft login page where I am unable to successfully log in.  I always get an error related to my username being unknown.

**Login URL I'm redirected to:**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=8c59ead7-d703-4a27-9e55-c96a0054c8d2&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmyaccount.microsoft.com%2F&client-request-id=72517e82-9593-437e-ab65-6d82f7805df4&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&x-client-SKU=msal.js.browser&x-client-VER=2.28.1&client_info=1&code_challenge=gWMCUzbutGYr2PL-1ijhmrtQF4gGeE-7CF1B9VAnVcY&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=1a3db4e6-c262-4aef-9dfe-ee3d151a6a10&state=eyJpZCI6IjMzZGQyMWRhLTdiNGQtNGYyNi1hODAzLTk1MWFhNGI4MzVmYiIsIm1ldGEiOnsiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25UeXBlIjoicmVkaXJlY3QifX0%3D
```

If I return to [microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/) I am still logged in.

It appears that Microsoft has 2 separate login databases, one at [microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/) and the other at [microsoftonline.com](https://login.microsoftonline.com).

Why can't I log in?

Answer (score 1):

#### Account Type

The distinction between the sites is the **account type**:

1. Links using `myaccount.microsoft.com` are for **organization** (Work / School) accounts.
2. Links that incorporate `account.microsoft.com` are for **personal** accounts.

Each time you switch from one site's URLs to the other,

1. your login session from one can't be used for the other, hence the login **prompt**;
2. your user account from one isn't valid on the other, hence the login **error** if you don't have both types of accounts.

Each site maintains its own URLs. For example, to see a list of devices attached to your account, depending on the type, the URL would be:

- **Personal Account**
  https://account.microsoft.com/devices *****
- **Organization Account**
  https://myaccount.microsoft.com/device-list

---

#### * Notes on site URLs and Redirection

Microsoft seems to have made some effort to redirect **organization** account users when they try to access URLs intended solely for **personal** account users, whereas no such effort appears to have been made in the other direction.

In the case where a **personal** URL supports account redirection, instead of a failed account login, when the **organization** account type is detected, the **organization** user is successfully authenticated and, regardless of the original URL, is redirected to their main "Account Overview" page: [myaccount.microsoft.com](https://myaccount.microsoft.com/).

The following **personal** account URL's all support account redirection in this manner:

- https://account.microsoft.com
- https://account.microsoft.com/privacy
- https://account.microsoft.com/devices
- https://account.microsoft.com/billing
- https://account.microsoft.com/billing/orders
- https://account.microsoft.com/profile

The following **personal** account URLs do not support account redirection:

- https://account.microsoft.com/security
- https://account.microsoft.com/rewards

As mentioned previously, I have yet to find a single **organization** URL that will perform any similar account redirection which makes the error in the [support document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/finding-your-bitlocker-recovery-key-in-windows-6b71ad27-0b89-ea08-f143-056f5ab347d6) that much more egregious.

The screenshots below are examples of the errors generated when failing to authenticate using a valid Microsoft account but on the wrong site (assuming no redirection):

**<sub>Error authenticating Personal Account on Organization Site</sub>**
[image]

**<sub>Error authenticating Organization Account on Personal Site</sub>**
[image]