# Can't log into Outlook because of Microsoft Authenticator code prompt

Tags: office-365, outlook-on-the-web, authentication, office-online

I typically use Google's applications and am less experienced with Microsoft products.

A client of mine, a private healthcare business, provided me with login details for an Outlook on the Web account but I have not been able to login to it.

When I attempt to login with the provided username and password, I am prompted to provide a code from the Microsoft Authenticator app.

If I instead try to login to the Microsoft Authenticator app using those credentials, I still get the authenticator code prompt which I can't provide since I'm not yet logged into it.

I have tried to use the same credentials to log into the Microsoft account at [accounts.microsoft.com](https://accounts.microsoft.com) but I get the following message:

> The Microsoft account doesn't exist. Enter a different account or get a new one.

How can I get access to the Outlook on the web email account?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. The question-and-answer platform that powers this site is not well suited to handle troubleshooting-like questions like this one. Unfortunately, there are no ready-to-use alternatives for new users. I'm referring to [chat], it requires to have a reputation > 20. Once said that you might improve the post to make a better fit for this site; please clarify what you mean by "log into Authenticator with the same login", add details to make it clear if you are using a consumer account or a managed account (i.e., an account given by a school or workplace).

Comment: It's a Outlook account that belongs to a private healthcare business. I have the login and password but cannot log in as I can't get past Microsoft Authenticator. What I mean is I use the same Outlook login to try and log into Authenticator. Login details are an email address and password. But on my most recent attempt at accounts.microsoft.com, a message said there is no Microsoft account for the email. So I really don't see how I can access the email at all.

Comment: I [edited](/posts/173897/edit) your question for clarity and to include the important details you posted in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

### Login URL

The account you are trying to access is an organization account (not personal), but the account URL you are using is for personal accounts.

That is why you are seeing the The *"Microsoft account doesn't exist..."* login error.

The correct login URL for organization accounts is [myaccount.microsoft.com](https://myaccount.microsoft.com).

Additional info in my answer to ["Error logging in to a Microsoft account..."](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/170941/)

### Authenticator Prompt

If you are being prompted for a Microsoft Authenticator verification code, it indicates that someone has configured the account for two-factor authentication (2FA).

By design, you will be blocked from the account regardless if you have the username and password unless you can pass 2FA.

### What to do

In order to login, you will need to:

1. Get whomever setup the 2FA to provide you a valid authenticator code; or
2. Leverage a backup/alternate 2FA option if one was configured and available to you; or
3. Have an admin/superuser for the organization's Microsoft 365 subscription assist you to gain access to the account.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to Google, Microsoft has several log-in workflows, i.e., some ask for the username/email address and password on the same login form, and there is one that uses two steps, one to ask the user's email address and that automatically sends the user to the corresponding second step, it might be the consumer / public accounts password request form, a generic password request form for managed accounts or to the corresponding login page for the school or workplace based on the organization/domain settings.

If you are using a Microsoft account given by the administrator, you should follow their directions to log in using that account. If you have missed those instructions, you should contact your administrator. You might also try to figure it out by your self, but if your organization is using a "Single Sign On" (SSO), it might take a while.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft Authenticator works very similar to Google Authenticator here.

You need whoever set up the email account to bind your account to your phone or other device running Microsoft authenticator.  They will give you more specific instructions on what is required for this.